# Dynamic query to find the length of rows in a column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to prepare a dynamic query to find the length of all the rows in a column in sql server. let say if there are 10 columns for a table with 100 rows. I need to find the row length for each column dynamically.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: Sample Data? expected result?

Comment: @UsmanMirza result should give the sum of length of rows for each column

Comment: @jarlh actually It should work for both, migration from sql server to postgresql, it should generate same result in both

Comment: @sumy, so you would like a single row result with a separate column containing total length of the column value? Is that just for string columns? What about other data types? The same query is not going to work for both DBMS products.

Comment: @sum y, so you want a total row at the end of result which have sum of length of each column right?

Comment: @DanGuzman actually I need a query for data validation i.e total data needs to be migrated from sql server to postgres, so to check the data i want that query, yes there are other data types as well

Comment: @UsmanMirza yes if there are 10 columns then result should have 10 column names along with length for rows in each column.

Comment: @sumy . . . Please explain what this is supposed to mean:  "I need to find the row length for each column dynamically."  The statement makes no sense to me.  Columns don't have "row lengths".

Comment: @GordonLinoff sum of the length of all the rows in that column- result should have table_name, column_name & the above sum

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your all columns are string columns, though `len` function should work anyways.

```
-- replace 'mytable' with the actual table name
declare @tableName nvarchar(128) = 'mytable';
declare @queryToRun nvarchar(max) = '';

-- IMPORTANT: following query is putting each column name as len_columnName
select  @queryToRun = @queryToRun + ', len([' + c.name + ']) as [len_' + c.name + ']
'
from    sys.tables as t
        inner join sys.columns as c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where   t.name = @tableName

-- removing the first comma
set @queryToRun = SUBSTRING(@queryToRun, 2, len(@queryToRun) - 1);

-- creating the query with dynamic column names
set @queryToRun = 'select ' + @queryToRun + ' from ' + @tableName;

--print @queryToRun

exec (@queryToRun)
```

Comment: Can u give it in this format - table_name, column_name & sum of the length of rows column wise

Comment: From [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**." [`DataLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) does not exclude trailing blanks. For Unicode strings you can use `DataLength( UnicodeStringExpression ) / DataLength( N'#' )` to get the length in characters. In general `DataLength( Left( Coalesce( StringExpression, '#' ), 1 ) )` will return the number of bytes per character.

Comment: @HABO, still I am NOT sure what OP is trying to do, that's why I kept it simple. Otherwise, yes what you are suggesting is correct and would give precise result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sys.tables` and `sys.all_columns`

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(max)='select '
select @Sql=@sql+'Sum(len('+QUOTENAME(c.name)+')) as Len'+QUOTENAME(c.name)+',' from sys.tables t join sys.all_columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id 
where t.Name='YourTableName'
set @Sql = left(@Sql,len(@sql)-1)+' from YourTableName' 
select @Sql
```

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: thank you for your practical tip , it's very useful in my language

Answer (score 0):

Try this Script you will get data length of each columns in table dynamically

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.LenghtOfRows')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE LenghtOfRows
CREATE TABLE LenghtOfRows (
                Id Int IDENTITY,
                Sqlode nvarchar(max)
                )
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max),
        @MinId INT,
        @MaxId INT,
        @tableName Varchar(100) ='StudentLabExamScore', --Give Table name here
        @GetSQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ''SELECT  DATALENGTH(''+COLUMN_NAME+'') As Len_'' +COLUMN_NAME +'' FROM ''+TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '''+@tableName+''''
PRINT @SQL

INSERT INTO LenghtOfRows(Sqlode)
EXEC ( @SQL)

SELECT @MinId = MIN(Id) from LenghtOfRows
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) from LenghtOfRows

WHILE (@MInId <=@MaxId)
BEGIN
SELECT @GetSQL= Sqlode FROM LenghtOfRows WHERE id=@MInId
EXEC (@GetSQL)
PRINT @GetSQL
SET @MInId=@MInId+1
END
```